# When I run 'sudo airmon-ng' in termux it throws a 'permission denied' error

Tags: linux, terminal, airmon-ng

I am using Termux in a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge Plus (SM-G928C) running Lineage OS 1.14.1 and android version 7 with root (SuperSU). When I run `sudo airmon -ng`, it throws the following error.

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 59: id: Permission denied
Unable to determine user id, permission errors may occur.
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 75: uname: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 110: wc: Permission denied
Your kernel has module support but you don't have modprobe installed.
It is highly recommended to install modprobe (typically from kmod).
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 183: ls: Permission denied

/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1202: ls: Permission denied
PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
```

Any idea on how to get it fixed?

Comment: root the device and run it as  root.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I am already running root. I've even granted root access every time I put in ```sudo```

Comment: Try dropping the do in "sudo" and use "su" - "sudo" requires a lookup of the userid in the sudo access file based on the command you're attemping fo use. In other words, what you can do as root is restricted. If you can't execute the command when using "su" then your root access is restricted . Also, the command "su" is typically not your path and you'll need root access to find it.

Comment: Ok so how do I unrestrict my root access. When I run ```su airmon-ng``` I get ```nobleltejv:/data/data/com.termux/files/home #```

Comment: The "su" command you are using was probably installed by the app. Can you "su"  and then" cd /mnt/secure" in 2 independent steps? The real "su" command will give you a "#" prompt when you type "su". Also, where did you locate the "su" command? Regarding on how to get the real "su" I can't help you - typically it requires rooting the cell phone.Further, I have no idea if you're simply using the command incorrectly - you may not need to root the device.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a fix. I got magisk instead of supersu and used su -c command and now it works fine. Thanks for all of your help.